# Apply same CSS to td of two different tables

Tags: html, css

Say I have two tables, each with their own class:

```
<table class="table1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Something</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Something else</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now what I'd like to do is apply the same css to the td's of each class. I know I can achieve this through the following css:

```
.table1 tbody td, .table2 tbody td{...}
```

However, I was wondering if there exists a syntax such that I can remove the commonalities and reduce this down to something like:

```
(.table1, .table2) tbody td{...}
```

I have already tried the syntax above with braces, brackets, and parenthesis and have had no success. I feel like this should be a rather simple thing to do but can't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: A work around is creating common class with common formatting and apply the class to the required element

Comment: I am aware of this work around. Would this be the best way to achieve what I want? In other words, does what I'm describing exist in CSS, or is a common class the closest thing to what I am describing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided there are other tables on your page that don't need the same styling, add a class to your tables (i.e. `.some-class`):

```
<table class="table1 some-class">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Something</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table2 some-class">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Something else</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then just apply the css to this class:

```
.some-class td {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a preprocessor like Sass if you want to use nested classes, like this:

**HTML**

```
<table class="t1"> 
  ....
</table>

<table class="t2"> 
  ....
</table>
```

**CSS (Sass)**

```
.t1,.t2{
  tr > td {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrqZpp

Comment: +1 for providing  a solution for what I was looking to do. Unfortunately I can't use Sass (or the likes) so I can't implement this solution, but I hadn't mentioned that in the question